# Facebook App Invites Swift No Notfications

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

Im trying to invite users to my app using facebook.

The facebook invite content is displayed correctly by calling `FBSDKAppInviteContent()`.

The problem is when i select a friend, they dont receive a notification(on facebook) or a push notification. What they do recieve is an "App invitation notification" which is visible on facebook `Apps > App invitations`

Ive tested the functionality using 2 test users from facebook developer console on 2 different physical devices.

I dont understand what im doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. Everything is working. Facebook will decide if to send a notificaiton or push notification.

Comment: Ok to be honest i dont really care about the push notifications. All i want is my invite to appear in the facebook `Notifications` not `App > App invitations`.  Is this not possible?

Comment: It may show up there. Facebook will decide depending on if Facebook thinks the person would click on the notification.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it works then i've filled empty fields "iPhone Store ID" and "iPad Store ID" in settings -> basic -> ios in developer section. Just after release in apple app store.